# Nodejs use method in view

Tags: node.js, pug

For example,In my Nodejs app,I have a router:

```
exports.test=function(req,res){ 
  res.render('./admin/test.jade',{html:[a,b,c]); 
}
```

And I have `Underscore.js`

In my view `test.jade`:

```
-var _und=require('Underscore.js')
....
div
  -_und.each(html,function(m))
    span m

....
```

But I got error.This shows that,the `Underscore.js` is just be used as a server-side method,how can I use a server-side method in view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to require underscore from a view. To view you should send just data (it means that in idea case you should not use underscore there at all). But if you would like, you can still send underscore like a function to view:

```
exports.test = function(req,res) { 
   res.render('./admin/test.jade',{ html: [a,b,c], _ : require("underscore") }); 
};
```

or like this:

```
exports.test = function(req,res) { 
   var underscore = require("underscore");
   res.render('./admin/test.jade', { html : [a,b,c], _ : underscore }); 
}
```

After in your view you can access to that like this:

```
div
  -_und.each(html,function(m))
    span m
```

You can get inspired from my nodejs github markdown project (http://bit.ly/1aOAG35). There is used underscore for layouting and I'm using it as well in templates:

```
{{# onlyblogs.forEach(function(current){ }}
<li>

<a href="..{{ current._fullpath }}">{{ current.title }}</a>

{{# if (current.description){ }}
<span>{{ current.description }}</span>
{{# } }}

<span>{{ current.category }}</span> in <date>{{ current.date }}</date>.

</li>
{{# }); }}
```

Hope that it helped.